# The directory name is invalid - Git and R Studio version control

Tags: git, rstudio

I'm trying to manage versions of my code using R Studio.

My question is similar to other (unresolved) SO questions:

1. 39720104
2. 21676188
3. 55684435
4. 53907248
5. 40952029

**"The directory name is invalid"**

This must be important and difficult to solve.

Now, I have a project in R Studio and a repository with the exact same name in Git.

These are the project cv options:

[image]

I have a SSH RSA Key.

This is my Environment tab:

[image]

And this is the message after clicking commit:

[image]

My RStudio version is:
Version 1.2.5042

Comment: Can you try running things on the terminal, if you don't mind? Then you can run the command and post the command the output in plain text in the question.

Comment: I think you are dealing with two variables here: git and R Studio. I would try to get rid of one of the variables: use git from terminal. At least then you could pinpoint to git as being the culprit. From my experience, git does not have problems with files that have non-ascii characters in the filename.... but I haven't tested any extreme cases, either way. A safe bet is, of course, to keep on using ascii-characters for the names of directories/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to remove the spaces from your folder names.

Comment: And the diacritical characters. Basically just limit yourself to ascii characters and no spaces and see what happens.

Comment: This should not be a problem if initializing the directory from the terminal (with `git init`).... just saying